# Storing in CoreData from Array of Dictionary objects

Tags: ios, core-data, dictionary, nsarray

I have an array `friendsArray` of dictionary objects which looks something like this:

```
(
        {
        name = "james p";
        phone = 345345345;
    },
        {
        name = "sam b";
        phone = 345345345;
    },
        {
        name = "aaron s";
        phone = 346346456;
    }
)
```

Now I'm storing it to coredata like this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *friends = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   for (int count = 0; count <[friendsArray count]; count++) {
    NSError *error;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FriendContacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *friendsObject  = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request         = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    friends = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:count];
    [friendsObject setValue:[friends objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [friendsObject setValue:[friends objectForKey:@"phone"] forKey:@"phone"];
    [context save:&error];

 }
```

Here is the screenshot of SQL Browser

[image]

It is storing data but making duplicate of this dictionary, I don't know why.

Comment: You haven't just run that code more than once have you? Try clearing out all the data - reset the simulator, and just run it once.

Comment: I tried that :) It does duplicate all the time. I know there is something I am doing wrong, just can't figure out what.

Comment: Add a log, you are running twice for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I just don't know whats happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - its a bit cleaner :)

Observe how many times the log statement is outputted and check the object it outputs.

```
 NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FriendContacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 for (NSDictionary *friend in friendsArray) {

    NSManagedObject *friendsObject  = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    [friendsObject setValue:[friend objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [friendsObject setValue:[friend objectForKey:@"phone"] forKey:@"phone"];

    NSLog(@"Created new friends object: %@", friendsObject);

    if ([context hasChanges]) {
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Problem saving changes: %@", error);
        }
    }
 }
```

EDIT:

You might also be better off saving after the loop is finished too (if you have a large data set), just move the `if` statement outside the loop.

Comment: OMG I called the same method twice. How stupid. Sorry to bother you guys.. Yes, I used fast enumeration before but then I switched to traditional for loop to check whats wrong I did lol..Thanks :)

Comment: @user3049559 its always the way. A note though, if you've got a lot of objects you'd be better off saving _after_ the loop. I've added an EDIT about this.